# how to make python multiprocessing pool memory efficient?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, memory, multiprocessing

I am trying to process a large amount of text with multiprocessing.

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import repeat

# ...import data...

type(train)
type(train[0])
```

output:

```
pandas.core.series.Series
str
```

I need to import a really large file (1.2GB) to use for my function. It is stored in an object named `Gmodel`.

My function takes 4 parameters, one of them being an object like `Gmodel`:

`my_func(text, model=Gmodel, param2, param3)`

Then I use the `multiprocessing.Pool` function:

```
from functools import partial

# make the multi-parameter function suitable for map 
# which takes in single-parameter functions
partial_my_func= partial(my_func, model=Gmodel, param2=100, param3=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(processes = 10, maxtasksperchild = 200)
    train_out = p.map(partial_my_func, train)
```

When I run the last 3 lines, and execute `htop` in my terminal, I see several processes with `VIRT` and `RES` over 20G. I am using a shared server and I'm not allowed to use so much memory. Is there a way for me to  cut memory usage here?

System information:

```
3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the text processing?

Comment: you could try multiprocessing.Manager with multiprocess.Process https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes